# How to output <> symbols instead of &lt;

Tags: java, jsoup

Possibly I'm using the wrong method but to insert Javascript into my document as I'm not getting my expected output here is  my code

```
String serachBoxLeft = "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://website/SearchBox/75070'></script>";
try{
Element search = doc.getElementById("hc_checkPrices").empty();
search = search.appendText(serachBoxLeft);
}catch (Exception e){

}

System.out.println(search);
```

The output I'm getting is

```
<div id="hc_checkPrices" class="hc_m_v2">
  &lt;script type='text/javascript' src='http://website/SearchBox/75070'&gt;&lt;/script&gt; 
</div>
```

Its tripping the code of the <> brackets

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If a method name is `appendText()` it's quite obvious that it'll treat given string as a text, not HTML fragment. Use [`Element.append(String html)` method](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) instead.